# How to calculate the average temperature of the hemispheres of a planet tidally locked to its star?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, planets, hard-science, temperature

I have a planet orbiting a red dwarf and, as expected, it is tidally locked to its star. I know that these planets will have a very significant temperature difference between the diurnal and nocturnal hemispheres, but I want to know how different it will be, that is to say, what will be the average temperature of both hemispheres if you take into account the warming of the diurnal side and the cooling of the nocturnal side. Is there any way to calculate it?

---

Keep in mind that:

1. The host star has a bolometric luminosity of 0.01 (Sun=1).
2. The planet's insolation is 4.85 (Earth=1).
3. The planet's semi-major axis is 0.05 AU.
4. The planet has an argon atmosphere, with small amounts of other gases (CO2, CH4, NH3, etc.).
5. The surface gravity is 0.75 (Earth=1)
6. The surface atmospheric pressure is 0.6 atm.
7. The albedo of the diurnal hemisphere is 0.4 and the albedo of the nocturnal hemisphere is 0.9 (Bond albedo).
8. The equilibrium temperature of the planet is 356 K for the hemisphere with the albedo of 0.4 and 228 K for the hemisphere with the albedo of 0.9.

Comment: @011358smell Of course, I will provide more details about the planet and its star.

Comment: To explain @011358smell's comment. Earth, *as seen from space*, has an average temperature of about −18 °C (0 °F); if it didn't reflect any of the sunlight received, it would have, as seen from space, an average temperature of about 5 °C (41 °F). However, because of the way Earth atmosphere and water cycle work, the actual average temperature *at the surface* of Earth is about 14 °C (57 °F). And this average is very misleading, masking differences between over 40 °C (105 °F) in Arabia in summer and less than −20 °C (-4 °F) in Novosibirsk in winter. And those are neither Antarctica nor Sahara.

Comment: @AlexP I am aware that the temperature on Earth varies greatly depending on location and season. I am also aware that greenhouse gases (and other factors) modify the average temperature of the planet. But I am trying to give a simple model, without considering so many factors. Basically, I am referring to the warming and cooling of the surface in each hemisphere as a function of time.

Comment: @011358smell The equilibrium temperature? No. The temperature on the diurnal side will be much higher than this and on the nocturnal side it will be much lower. I'm talking about how constant sunshine (and lack of it) affects the average temperature in each hemisphere.

Comment: This has the potential to be a *really good question*, I'm concerned that it might get closed as opinion based or too broad . Please be patient, there may be some here who can give you an answer.

Comment: Just to be clear, we are not talking about an [eyeball planet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyeball_planet) here, are we? They are an artifact of early simulations with extremely simple atmosphere models. Later simulations show that the matter is very complex and a lot of things can happen. The current leading idea is that atmospheric circulation will disperse the heat quite equally over the planet. The wind will create a warm band reaching into the shadow and a cold spike reaching into the light along its path of rotation?

Comment: Also that argon atmosphere needs some explanations. Is it "natural" Argon-36 or radiogenic Argon-40 like on Earth? Why is there so much natural argon on the world? Or how did radioactive decay create so much argon? Also you want CH4 and NH3 but no H2O in the atmospere. These ices usually come together. Finally, why is there no N2? Most other nitrogen rich chemicals are volatile and nitrogen does isn't bout in rocks. It will usually either escape the planet or accumulate in the atmospere.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight There's molecular nitrogen in the atmosphere, but in small amounts. Its shortage is due to the fact that it could not be degassed due to the absence of tectonic plates (as occurred on Venus and Mars), it was trapped underground. Unlike the Earth, the dominant isotope of argon in the atmosphere is not argon-40, but argon-36. This was trapped by the planet directly from space and was not caused by the decay of potassium-40 in rocks (as is the case with argon-40). The large amount of argon is due to the high metallicity of the star. I forgot to mention water vapor.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight And yes, it is an eyeball planet: one hemisphere is a hot desert and the other is a cold desert. However, there is no terraformed region in the terminator.

Comment: Venus has a lot of N2, about 3.3 bar, in its atmosphere. The thin martian atmosphere has about 2% CO2. The degassing is in no way related to tectonic plates, plate tectonics only started much later on Earth, about 3.2 byr ago. Nitrogen simply won't remain trapped underground. Secondly if the star has a high metallicity, it means that there will be a lot of uranium and Thorium, ultimately leading to a lot of Argon 40.

Comment: The only way to get the classical eyeball planet is to have no (significant) atmosphere. Just Google up some papers on "atmospheric circulation of tidally locked planets", make sure they used a 3D atmosphere model and you'll see why the are no eybasll planets. I've seen simulations where the day side / night side temperature difference was only about 20 K.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight Thanks for the tips! I will take them into account.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight That's... interesting. I mean, day/night temperature difference is about 20 K where I live on average even without tidal locking. I've been clearly underestimating just how much heat transfer can be provided even by a relatively thin (compared to e.g. Venus) Earth-like atmosphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked "Is there any way to calculate it?". The answer is yes, but it's not going to be as simple as plugging a few numbers into a simple formula.

You'll need a [general circulation model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_circulation_model).

The reason is that the heat transport around the planet involves the atmosphere and the oceans, and these require dealing with fluid dynamics. This is going to bring in dependencies like the topography of the planet (the wind is going to be affected by obstacles such as mountain ranges, likewise the oceans are going to respond to the shape of the ocean basins). And just to make things worse, the oceans and atmosphere are coupled. You'll also need to deal with annoying things that aren't very well constrained, like cloud formation, which affects the albedo of the planet.

Needless to say, this is rather computationally intensive (do you have a supercomputer to hand?), and even if you find an available GCM you'll likely have to do a lot of modifications so it can be applied to a tidally-locked exoplanet, especially if the atmosphere is non-Earthlike as well.

One model I've seen being used for a bunch of exoplanet studies is LMDZ4, as used e.g. for [Proxima b](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.06827). Not sure if the source code is freely available though and even if it were, I'm not sure whether it would be executable on standard desktop hardware.

Otherwise you could try to fudge it by throwing in a simple redistribution factor and emissivity into the usual effective temperature formula. With stellar luminosity $L_\ast$, planet-star distance $d$, emissivity $\epsilon$, albedo $A$ and the fraction of energy distributed to the nightside $f \in [0, 0.5]$ where 0.5 means an equal fraction of energy distributed to both hemispheres, equating received and emitted power and you end up with:

$$\begin{align}
T_\mathrm{d} & = \left[\frac{L_\ast (1-A) (1-f)}{8 \pi d^2 \cdot \sigma \epsilon_\mathrm{d}}\right]^{1/4} \\
T_\mathrm{n} & = \left[\frac{L_\ast (1-A) f}{8 \pi d^2 \cdot \sigma \epsilon_\mathrm{n}}\right]^{1/4}
\end{align}$$

Where $\sigma$ is the Stefan-Boltzmann constant. The d and n suffixes represent the day and nightside, and I've allowed for different emissivities of both hemispheres (e.g. due to cloud buildup on the dayside versus clearer skies at night).

But figuring out what the appropriate values for $A$, $\epsilon_\mathrm{d,n}$ and $f$ are basically requires doing things properly.

---

Derivation of the formulae:

For a planet orbiting at distance $d \gg R_\ast$ where $R_\ast$ is the radius of the star (i.e. negligible illumination of the far hemisphere, light rays can be treated as parallel), the fraction of the power output of the star intercepted is the ratio of the area of the planetary disc, $\pi R_\mathrm{p}^2$, where $R_\mathrm{p}$ is the planetary radius, to the area over which the star's radiation is distributed across, i.e. a sphere of radius $d$, which has area $4\pi d^2$. The albedo $A$ represents the fraction of this reflected back into space, so the absorbed power is:

$$P_\mathrm{abs} = L_\ast (1-A) \left(\frac{R_\mathrm{p}^2}{4d^2}\right)$$

For the planet to be in equilibrium, the power radiated must equal the power absorbed. Assume the planet has two hemispheres, with uniform properties across each hemisphere. Energy balance gives

$$P_\mathrm{rad,d} + P_\mathrm{rad,n} = P_\mathrm{abs}$$

So representing the fraction of the power transferred to the nightside by $f$, we can write:

$$\begin{align}
P_\mathrm{rad, d} & = (1-f)P_\mathrm{abs} \\
P_\mathrm{rad, n} & = fP_\mathrm{abs}
\end{align}$$

The next stage is to write the greybody emission law for each hemisphere. The total area of each hemisphere is $2\pi R_\mathrm{p}^2$, the power per unit area at a given temperature $T$ is $\sigma T^4$, and we scale by the emissivity $\epsilon$:

$$\begin{align}
P_\mathrm{rad,d} & = 2\pi R_\mathrm{p}^2 \cdot \epsilon_\mathrm{d} \sigma T_\mathrm{d}^4 \\
P_\mathrm{rad,n} & = 2\pi R_\mathrm{p}^2 \cdot \epsilon_\mathrm{n} \sigma T_\mathrm{n}^4
\end{align}$$

Substituting these expressions into the previous ones gives the formulae in the text above.

Comment: You got my attention with those formulas, where did you get them exactly?

Comment: @URIZEN - added the derivation, hope that helps.